# cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); SqlException Unhandled

Tags: c#

Every time I click the button without a value (null, or blank), I get an error.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Fifth_Attempt
{
    class Prof
    {
        public SqlException AddProfessorInformation(ProfModel oPM)

        {
            string connStr = @"Data Source=USER-PC;Integrated Security=True;";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ProfInfo(ID,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Department,Username,Password)  VALUES(@LRN,@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName,@Department,@Username,@Password)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", oPM.ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", oPM.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", oPM.MiddleName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", oPM.LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", oPM.Department);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", oPM.Username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", oPM.Password);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return null;         

        }
    }
}
```

[>link to full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sVMG.png)

why do I get the error?

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Please include your code & error as text.

Comment: from where @LRN coming from ? I don't see any in image attached. Possibly some typo in values section which kind of clipped of in image you provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why add parameter for @LRN missing ?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LRN", ??);
```

Comment: Well, seems that is my mistakes.